# sort array of object with same value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i have an array of object, and one element of the object is an array

example array to sort:

```
[
  {id: 1, values: ['a','b']},
  {id: 2, values: ['c','d']},
  {id: 3, values: ['b']},
  {id: 4, values: ['c']},
  {id: 5, values: ['e']},
]
```

i need to make a function to pass to the sort function that given a value string, start the sorting of item with that value and continue with other items that have the same value:

sorted example array given **'b'**:

```
by id: 1,3,2,4,5
```

so first it will put all the items with a 'b' value, then the next element, could be anything, ad after that the other items that have the same value, (id 2,4 have c in common) and so on

i hope that i've explained it good enough, thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why it should not be 3,1,5,2,4 or 1,3,5,4,2, or still something else?

Comment: not really, maybe another good rule is to sort first the one with the most same value (1,3 or 2,4 ) then the other, and in this case 1,3 but it can be 3,1 i was thinking that following the array order i will find 1 first than 3

Comment: I see, so 5 would certainly have to be at the end, but 1,3 can be swapped, and also 2,4 can be swapped, right? Unless you want to follow index order, then it is fixed.

Comment: What if there was also an `{id: 6, value:['a']}`, would it have to be selected sooner than 5 or not? I thought of the `a` in the first object, but since it was already selected with the `b`, maybe it doesn't count anymore for later selections... Can you clarify?

Comment: yes in my example 5 would be at the end, index is not really important but easier maybe ... also if i have` {id:6 values['a']}` it would go at the end because i passed letter b so 1 and 3 would already be sorted at first, then the rest base on the number of same other values, hope it's more clear now

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification. One more thing: how large is the data set (in number of objects, and number of items in `values` array)?

Comment: around few hunder max less then 1000 usually

Comment: Do you really need the function to be an argument for `sort`, or can the solution also be a function that takes care of the sorting as a whole?

Comment: sort argument is preferred but it can be a stand alone function if not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do this with a callback function for `sort`, since the order of two objects does not depend only on these objects themselves, but on all objects. This would mean that for every call of the callback the whole input has to be processed, eliminating the higher priority objects, to then find out which of the two given objects would come first. This would give a rather inefficient algorithm.

Instead, define a function that does the sorting.

It would repeatedly find the value that occurs most often, and then output the objects that have that value. Care has to be taken to remove those objects as candidate once they are output.

Here is an implementation:

```js
function sortByFrequency(data, selectedValue) {
    // Key the data by id
    const remaining = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({id, values}, idx) => [id, {values, idx}]));
    // Create inverse data structure (for a given value, give the associated ids)
    const idsWithValue = {};
    for (const {id, values} of data) {
        for (const value of values) {
            (idsWithValue[value] ??= new Set).add(id);
        }
    }
    const results = [];
    while (results.length < data.length) {
        if (selectedValue) {
            // Output the (remaining) objects that have the selected value:
            for (const id of idsWithValue[selectedValue]) {
                results.push(data[remaining[id].idx]);
                for (const value of remaining[id].values) {
                    idsWithValue[value].delete(id); // Remove this id as association for a value
                }
            }
        }
        let maxLength = 0;
        // Find the value with the most associated ids:
        for (const [value, ids] of Object.entries(idsWithValue)) {
            if (ids.size > maxLength) {
                maxLength = ids.size;
                selectedValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}

// Example run
const data = [
  {id: 1, values: ['a','b']},
  {id: 2, values: ['c','d']},
  {id: 3, values: ['b']},
  {id: 4, values: ['c']},
  {id: 5, values: ['e']},
  {id: 6, values: ['a']},
  {id: 7, values: ['b']},
];
const results = sortByFrequency(data, "b");
console.log(results);
```

The efficiency could be improved by making use of an efficient priority queue implementation. But as JavaScript offers no native priority queue, you'd have to include a library or create your own. So I left that consideration aside.

Comment: pretty interesting, but it also need to have a starting value (optional) if present it should first find all the element that have that value as first then the most frequent

Comment: Updated the answer to take that initial optional argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

1. Loop the data and take the `id`s of any object that contains the target letter.
2. Filter out those taken data
3. Sort the filtered data by the first letter in the `values` array alphabetically.
4. Loop the sorted data and take the `id`s into the result array.

*Change the `data` to see any test cases you want.*

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, values: ['a','b']},
  {id: 2, values: ['c','d']},
  {id: 3, values: ['b']},
  {id: 4, values: ['c']},
  {id: 5, values: ['e']},
  {id: 6, values: ['a']},
  {id: 7, values: ['b']},
]
function sortByLetter(data, letter){
  let dataClone = data.map(a => ({...a}));
  let result = [];
  dataClone.forEach(d => {
    if (d.values.includes(letter)) {
      result.push(d.id);
    }
  })
  let filteredData = dataClone.filter(d => !result.includes(d.id));
  filteredData.sort((a, b) => a.values[0].localeCompare(b.values[0]))
  filteredData.forEach(fd => result.push(fd.id))
  return result;
}
console.log(sortByLetter(data,'b'));
```

Comment: it's working quite as expected, but i will edit to return the data array sorted not only the index (the output example for me was only to simplify the order,but i need the array ordered )

Comment: i think just removing the .id when pushing to result and check in filteredData will do the trick

Comment: this doesn't order by the highest number of same values (5 elment with same value, go before a value that only 3 element have in common)